# save data to another table after creating django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i have two models ImageShoot and Image.

models.py:

```
class ImageShoot(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     # image = models.URLField(name=None)
      created_at = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name
class Image(models.Model):
      license_type = (
         ('Royalty-Free','Royalty-Free'),
         ('Rights-Managed','Rights-Managed')
     )

      image_number = models.CharField(default=random_image_number,max_length=12)
      title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'home/tboss/Desktop/image' , default = 'home/tboss/Desktop/image/logo.png')
      category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      shoot = models.ForeignKey(ImageShoot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      image_keyword = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
      credit = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
      location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
      license_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=license_type, default='')
      uploaded_at = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.title
```

admin.py:

```
class Imageset(admin.ModelAdmin):
      associated_images = ImageShoot.image_set.all()
      return associated_images

admin.site.register(Image)
admin.site.register(ImageShoot,Imageset)
```

what i am trying to achieve that when i create a image it should show on imageshoot also like when i create image in shoot 1. this image should show on shoot 1.
i am not sure which field should i add on imageshoot.

Comment: did you mean one image will have the multiple shot

Comment: one imageshoot will have multiple image

Comment: i think you have to reverse the foreignkey and use a post save signal

Comment: whats issues in the current ??

Comment: yeah i also think i have to use postsave but how can i add  clickable image field

Comment: when i click on shoot it should all the clickable image model of this particular shoot

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Reverse lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)**

In Your views you can get all the images associated with the `ImageShoot` Obj using `set`.Try this in your shell after briefly going through the docs

`associated_images = ImageShoot.image_set.all()`

- You can also use django orm methods for querysets like `filter`, `count`, etc.

---

**Edit:**

To display related images you can use this in admin:

```
@admin.register(ImageShoot)
class Imageset(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'created_at', 'associated_images')  
    def associated_images(self, obj):
        return obj.image_set.all()     #<----edit
    associated_images.admin_order_field = 'imageshoot_image'
```

Comment: its working on shell but when i am trying this to add in Imageshoot model it shows imageshoot not defined

Comment: Coz its `ImageShoot` and also check your import. Paste the error

Comment: yes i'm adding ImageShoot but what do you mean by import

Comment: Have you imported the `ImageShoot` model in views? something like this `from .models import ImageShoot`

Comment: i am trying to add on admin and i'm usimg drf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204486/discussion-between-ans2human-and-afk).